# Chrome can't handle animations at large screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, animation

This is a very peculiar thing that is happening and I was wondering if anybody could shed some insight on why it might be occurring.

My website is http://bmgzstrategies.com/

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to the 4th section, case studies (http://bmgzstrategies.com/#5)
- Click on a thumbnail
- If your screen size is smaller than about
  1450px, a window should load from the right side of the screen and
  three copy sections should load sequentially.
- Now, if you increase
  your screen size to larger than 1450px wide, and click on a
  thumbnail, the animation becomes completely broken and choppy and
  suddenly the end state is in front of you.

I have failed to reproduce this error in Safari (so it's likely not a webkit problem), Mozilla, or Internet Explorer.

If anybody has any insight I'd love to hear any opinions!

Comment: Not sure why that happens, maybe Jquery is the problem unless you are using plain CSS transitions. I'm using a plugging called velocity which performs all that a lot better and faster than the native JQ. If you are using JQ it may worth a look to see what it can do for you. -- http://julian.com/research/velocity/

Comment: Hey Tasos!  I am using CSS animations from Animate.css.  And I'm using them in multiple locations on the site, which are not breaking.  It is only this one instance on this one page that is not working correctly.  Very weird...

Comment: How do the the animations perform on a full HD screen 1920x1080.? *** Update. I Just tried in FULL HD on my screen and the performance is very Poor. You are right though, On Chrome the performance is not great but IE is much better. Strange, i would have have thought it would be the other way round. Maybe there are some bugs in the current Version. Try and download CHROMIUM that should be the updated version of chrome and see if its any better

Comment: I updated chrome and tried it again and it's still not working.  No idea why this is occurring, or how to debug this..

Comment: Well on Chrome you have Developer tools for debugging. You can Run (Audit) To check Web Page Performance. Once its finished it will present you with a Page Suggesting Changes to all sorts including CSS for better Performance.

Comment: Chrome 37 for Mac on a 2013 MacBook Pro doesn't have any issues on a 1080p screen...

Comment: I tried running the site on my iMac at work and the site is working fine.  Mac OSX 10.8.5 2560x1440... this makes no sense.  Is also occurring on Chrome on PC

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason this turned out to be a layering issue with the CSS library I was using.  The animation would run and, on large screen sizes, the z-index of the affected divs would be reset.  By fixing the z-index of the divs that were flashing, I was able to eliminate the behavior.